# External Seagate Hard drive for Mac - Compatibility

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro, external-disk, disk-format

I am looking to purchase a Seagate External Hard Drive for my MacBook Air.

The products claims it works only with PC (windows), however, I have read multiple places that I can just format the drive and it will work fine with a mac.

1) Is this a correct statement. I assume it is but I am new to OSX and like to check.

2) What is the process to format an external drive? (Using OS X 10.9)

Comment: Buyer beware! I have seen this kind of thing before where a manufacturer states only windows and even after reformatting the drive it doesn't work after a week or so. Please consider looking for something that has the official "Made for Mac" logo. A perfect example of this is at: http://www.wd.com/en/ notice that it has a different section for drives and drives for mac. If you like the Seagate then purchase it from somewhere with a good return policy

Comment: @AndrewU. - Amazon has a good return policy. => After posting here I came across another review saying it works just fine with a mac as long as you format it first.

Comment: @AndrewU.,  Is it **even possible** that a disk can't be reformated to work for Mac? Aren't disks just disks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as the drive connects to your MacBook Air via a connection protocol that the Air supports like Thunderbolt or USB 2 or USB 3 you can format the drive and use it with your Mac just fine.

To format an external hard drive on your Mac (paraphrased [from here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/04/format-an-external-hard-drive-or-usb-flash-drive-for-mac-os-x/)):

1. Connect the drive to your Mac
2. Open `Applications > Utilities > Disk Utility`
3. On the left hand side of Disk Utility you'll see a list of drives. Find your external drive and select it.
4. Select the `Erase` tab and choose `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` for the format and give it a name
5. Press the `Erase` button to kick off the process. **NOTE**: This will erase everything currently on the hard drive!

Comment: It is a USB 3 drive so it will connect. Thank you for the information!